# Error: method was not declared in this scope (but it is included)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt, compiler-errors, subdirectory

I have two folders, f1 and f2, and they are on same level (have same folder for parent). In f1 I have source code of my project, and in f2 I have unit tests.

The problem occurs when I try to include file from my project into unit test class. I just get this:

```
natty:/tmp/test/f2$ qmake-qt4 .
natty:/tmp/test/f2$ make
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtTest -I../f1 -I. -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtTest -I../f1 -I. -o tcommon.o tcommon.cpp
tcommon.cpp: In member function ‘void tcommon::tCalculateMD5_str()’:
tcommon.cpp:21:50: error: ‘CalculateMD5’ was not declared in this scope
tcommon.cpp: In member function ‘void tcommon::tCalculateMD5_uint()’:
tcommon.cpp:43:50: error: ‘CalculateMD5’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [tcommon.o] Error 1
```

What is going on? The code in relevant files is, `test/f2/tcommon.cpp`:

```
#include "tcommon.h"
#include <common.h>

// ...

void tcommon::tCalculateMD5_str()
{
    QFETCH(QString, string);
    QFETCH(QString, result);

    // THIS IS LINE 21 <-----------------------------------------------
    QCOMPARE(CalculateMD5(string), result);
}
// ...
```

And here is `common.h` from `test/f1/common.h` (the include is found just fine):

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H

#include <QtCore>

QString CalculateMD5(uint number);
QString CalculateMD5(QString str);

#endif // COMMON_H
```

Here is project that won't compile (3 kb):
http://www.xx77abs.com/test2.rar

Comment: (a) Yeah, that's my bad, wrong words :P (b) OK. (c) Can you tell me how, or maybe give me a link or something so I can research further ?? (d) Well you can unpack it and you'll get an example of what's not working ... I think it's better than copying/pasting code in my question.

Comment: @xx77aBs: I just fixed your problem. Your question was indeed puzzling and the description misguided to a degree. However, you did have a real, legitimate and understandable problem. I hope you will learn lot's of cool things about C :)

Comment: @xx77aBs: Creating [a short, reproducible testcase](http://sscce.org/) is the appropriate mechanism for a programming question. 99.99999999% of your code will be completely irrelevant to the issue at hand.

Comment: @Tomalak: I think you're not being very fair. I doubt whether you actually looked at the code. It is 79 lines of (sparse) code. It's basically a tweaked hello world console app. The fact that the OP _thought_ that the folder structure was important, required him to put up an archive, instead of posting the 79 lines.

Comment: @sehe: No, I didn't look at it at all. A SO question should be self-contained; hosting parts of it elsewhere is inappropriate and prone to link rot.

Comment: Tried to make the question more selfcontained. Short of including a base64 encoded tarball (would only be 53 lines in fact) it is the best anyone could do, I suppose

Comment: To all: Thank you again ! I will try to learn from your advices. I am sorry that my question was misleading ... I've just written what I thought was the problem - the problem that caused my application not to work. I've just changed that one letter mistake (#ifdef in header) and everything works. Thank you again, especially you sehe :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have duplicated the header guards from f1/common.h in f2/tcommon.h.

Change these to (in tcommon.h):

```
#ifndef TCOMMON_H
#define TCOMMON_H

//...

#endif // TCOMMON_H
```

and the problem is fixed, the program builds and you can run it. In response: `fixed.zip` (see [source of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7375611/revisions))

Comment: Must be quite a strange code layout if this caused a linker error. Function definition in a header file, and declarations for the same function in a different header file?

Comment: @Tomalak: nope, just two unrelated headers with the same header guard. You know how that goes: the header included first wins

Comment: Oh, by the way, it was _not_ a linker error; undeclared, not undefined or unresolved

Comment: Ah, that makes all the difference. So the _only_ piece of concrete information given in the question was flat out wrong.

Comment: @sehe Thank you very much !! I must've overseen this (damn that replace all and late night coding :P). (==To all==) Thank you for your comments. I will try to use all your advices :)